# Entity Framework Ignore property by conventions

Tags: entity-framework, properties, conventions

I have a code-first model where all entities are derived from a `Entity` base class. I have a property `IsDeleted` in base class which I want to ignore in all entities (I cannot remove/comment IsDeleted property since base class is used in many projects). Is there a way to configure `modelBuilder` to ignore this property form all entities (by conventions, I think), without to specify `modelBuilder.Entity<...>().Ignore(l => l.IsDeleted)` for all entities from my model?

Thanks, 
Ion

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using the new EF 6.1 [Custom Code First Conventions](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions):

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c => c.Ignore("IsDeleted"));
```

This will ignore any property of the name `IsDeleted` in any of your types.

If you only want to do this for classes inheriting a certain base class, you can do:

```
modelBuilder.Types()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseClass)))
            .Configure(c => c.Ignore("IsDeleted"));
```

Comment: I'm using EF 6.0, and this works for all non-explicit implementers:

`modelBuilder.Types<IIdentifiableEntity>().Configure(c => c.Ignore<int>(i=> i.EntityId));`

Comment: How do I ignore ALL properties of a base class? What happens if I ignore the base type, while declaring entity sets of the sub type? Can I use an `EntityBase` this way, if I don't care about non POCOs?

Comment: Broken link.  Please update if available.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` annotation on the properties, but that will still need to be added for each entity which isn't the same as only specifying it once and having a convention for ignoring it.