# Entity Framework 6 with POCO Using Only Some Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have multiple classes used in another VS project that are interconnected, e.g.:

```
namespace MyOtherProject
{
    public class A {
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class B {
        public int Value {get;set;}
        public A Child {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now I want to use these classes as POCO for code first in EF. However I don't need all classes in the database but only some of them. So I created a context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext () : base("MyContext ")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the project I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   MyProject.A: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type
>   name 'A' is already defined.

Note that the namespace in the error is not the same as the definition of the class A because my class A is defined in another (shared) project. Instead the namespace is the one of the context.

On https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application I read this:

> You could have omitted the DbSet and DbSet
>   statements and it would work the same. The Entity Framework would
>   include them implicitly because the Student entity references the
>   Enrollment entity and the Enrollment entity references the Course
>   entity.

My assumption (not confirmed) is that EF sees that B references A but there is no dataset of type A, so it generates internally a class A and then suddenly finds out there are two such classes.

Anyone know what the exact problem is and what I can do to fix it? I have too many classes that I don't really need, so I don't want to create datasets for each class I have.

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<MyContext >(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext >()); can you add above code inside your context constructor and check

Comment: Sometimes this problem related to your DB_migration

Comment: The database already exists, I cannot create it.

Comment: If you have database already exist , you can use **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** option  if new databse created then we can understand the problem is in migration

Comment: you can use migration up and down method to solve your problem..!

Comment: The problem is not in the database because the exception is thrown before any access to the database is attempted - just when I try to to create a new context instance.

Comment: oh oh you are using A class reference inside the B Poco Class then how can you create a DBSET B alone without A????

Comment: I don't need a dataset of type A because I am not using it, it is only used in other projects. I.e. in my project I will never use the property B.Child but it exists and I cannot mark it as NotMapped (because of the other projects I cannot change the classes).

Comment: What about `modelBuilder.Entity<B>().Ignore(x => x.Child)`?

Comment: I think that might work but I have about 300 classes with each 100 properties - it will be a bit difficult to remove them all. So I was looking for a possibility to say "ignore all that I have not explicitly stated" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get all generic type parameters(`Type1`, `Type2`...) from `DbSet<Type1>`. Then you should check for each of this types their internal properties types, i.e. references to another types (as direct link or via `ICollection` set), - if this internal types not exist at first *tablesTypes* set we will ignore them.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {         
        //other stuff.....

        Func<Type, bool> genericFilter = x => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1;

        //All types of your context tables
        var tablesTypes = GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => genericFilter(x.PropertyType))
            .Select(x => x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First());

        var namespaces2ignore = new List<string> { "Namespace2Ignore1", "Namespace2Ignore2" };
        var toIgnore = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var type in tablesTypes)
            //Ignore internal types, which not exist at tablesTypes
            toIgnore.AddRange(type.GetProperties()
                .Select(x => genericFilter(x.PropertyType) ? x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First() : x.PropertyType)
                .Where(x => !tablesTypes.Contains(x) && namespaces2ignore.Contains(x.Namespace)
                /*or as you suggested: && typeof(A).Assembly == x.Assembly*/
            ).ToList());            

        modelBuilder.Ignore(toIgnore);
    }
```

If you want to add condition on specific pairs type-property you can do something like that:

```
    foreach (var type in tablesTypes)
        foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new { type = genericFilter(x.PropertyType) ? x.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First() : x.PropertyType, prop = x })
            .Where(x => !tablesTypes.Contains(x.type) && namespaces2ignore.Contains(x.type.Namespace)                
        ).ToList())
            if(!(type == typeof(TestType) && prop.prop.Name == "Test"))
                toIgnore.Add(prop.type);
```

Now won't be excluded property with name "Test" of type `TestType`.

Comment: Won't this also remove any properties of simple types like string, int? So maybe I have to check also that the type of the property is inside my assembly with incorrect types but that's easy to add.

Comment: Yes, good comment. At this case you can check - is current type declared at specific Assembly or is it belogs to some list of namespaces(as demonstrated in my corrected answer)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore properties and not types only? Based on their PropertyInfo

Comment: Why not? You can add new filter, as shown at my modified answer.

Comment: Using your suggestion and some hints from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066906/ignoring-all-properties-but-some-in-entity-framework-6 I succeeded to fix it. Thanks a lot!